# mist wallet automatically connects to privatenet instead of testnet

Tags: mist, testnets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I downloaded the mist wallet for ethereum and when i open up the program it sometimes connects me automatically to the private-net instead of the test-net. In this case i don't know how to change back and connect to the test-net. The option from the tab develop>network>testnet is grey (disabled).
In addition is there a way to change the setting of mist wallet and connect to ropsten testnet instead of morden? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have private testnet geth process running on background?

Comment: I don't think so. When i was downloading the blockchain it took forever (no peers in morden) so i used the command  geth --testnet --fast (not much changed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the new update to mist wallet 0.8.8 the problem is resolved. The Ropsten network is the default testnet for the new mist wallet. However if you still want to play around with the previous version of mist wallet check this article out:
https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/11/20/from-morden-to-ropsten/